# LinkedIn Company Statistics API not returning Job Functions

Tags: linkedin-api

We're having an issue with the [company-statistics api](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/company-pages#statistics) in LinkedIn. Both from our client and from the api console, the job functions array is not being returned. This was working as of two days ago, then it stopped.

Specifically, calling

`https://api.linkedin.com/v1/companies/{id}/company-statistics`

with a few different company ids and credentials, we're not getting that functions array back. It's not empty, it's not even present.

Has there been some change to the API or is this a temporary problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that this was in fact a temporary (though 1 month long) problem on their end. They started returning functions and some other fields that were missing yesterday.